# Change to date format with R

Tags: r, date

I have a list with the column that has values with this format: `11/1/2017 0:00`. The type of this column is said to be `integer`. How can change this date just to `1/11`?

Thanks

Comment: It is strange to have that format having class `integer`.  Perhaps `format(as.Date("11/1/2017 0:00", "%m/%d/%Y"), "%d/%m")`

Comment: It might be a factor column

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- lubridate::mdy_hm(x) 
x <- sprintf("%s/%s", lubridate::month(x), lubridate::day(x))
```